# snipping tool in Chrome Extension not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension, that has a snip tool I've been working on.  Its almost working as I'd like, the issue is it seems that as soon as I load a webpage it executes the whole process, where I'm intending to have the user click a button and then it starts the process.

So, I've based on this on the CaptureVisibleTab API and I have to communicate between some scripts to do this.

To start my manifest.json (relevant info)

```
"manifest_version": 3,
permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "tabs",
      "contextMenus",
      "scripting",
      "storage",
      "identity"
    ],
"background": {
      "service_worker": "scripts/background.js"
},

"content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
      "all_frames": false,
      "run_at": "document_end"
```

I have a button on the popup.HTML that has a id called "snip", pretty self explanitory

then in the popup.js there's a variable for the snip and a event listener to then que the screenshot

```
var snip = document.getElementById("snip");

snip.addEventListener("click", function() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "captureVisibleTab" }, function(response) {
    console.log(response.imageUrl);
  });
});
```

Now in background.js it has a listener for the action
and just returns the image result to then be cropped, and sent to the content script

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === "captureVisibleTab") {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, { format: "png" }, function(imageUrl) {
      sendResponse({ imageUrl: imageUrl });
    });
    return true; // Required to indicate that the response will be sent asynchronously
  }
});
```

finally in the content.js, I just have the function and the message for the captureVisibleTab
where when it gets it, it takes the image of the webapge and passes it as a argument in the function

```
function cropScreenshot(imageUrl) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var isMouseDown = false;
    var startX, startY, endX, endY;
  
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      canvas.style.display = "block";
      var overlay = document.createElement("div");
      overlay.style.position = "absolute";
      overlay.style.top = "0";
      overlay.style.left = "0";
      overlay.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
      overlay.style.height = canvas.height + "px";
      overlay.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
      document.body.appendChild(overlay);
  
      overlay.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
        isMouseDown = true;
        startX = e.offsetX;
        startY = e.offsetY;
      });
  
      overlay.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
        isMouseDown = false;
        endX = e.offsetX;
        endY = e.offsetY;
        var width = endX - startX;
        var height = endY - startY;
        if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
          var croppedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
          var croppedCtx = croppedCanvas.getContext("2d");
          croppedCanvas.width = width;
          croppedCanvas.height = height;
          croppedCtx.drawImage(canvas, startX, startY, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
          var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
          downloadLink.href = croppedCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          downloadLink.download = "snipped-img.png";
  
          // Attach the anchor to the document and click it
          document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
          downloadLink.click();
  
          // Remove the anchor from the document
          document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
        }
        canvas.style.display = "none";
        overlay.remove();
      });
  
      overlay.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
        if (isMouseDown) {
          var width = e.offsetX - startX;
          var height = e.offsetY - startY;
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)";
          ctx.fillRect(startX, startY, width, height);
        }
      });
    };
    img.src = imageUrl;
  }

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "captureVisibleTab" }, function(response) {
    if (response && response.imageUrl) {
      // Call the cropScreenshot function and pass the imageUrl as a parameter
      var imageUrl = response.imageUrl
      cropScreenshot(imageUrl);
    } else {
      console.log("Error capturing visible tab");
    }
  });
```

that is the gist of it, I have tried putting a action between popup and background, like startSnip, but that doesn't work.  This as it sits is currently the closest I've come to getting it right.  So I'm sure its something obvious now, and I just can't see it.  any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please describe the sequence of steps, e.g., open web page, click extension icon, dialog opens, etc.  And at which step does it break?  Have you checked console for errors (there's usually something with message problems). Are there any errors listed in the Chrome extension manager page? What does "as I load a webpage it executes" mean? It does that even without the popup displayed?

Comment: There is a bug in content.js. You need to send a message when an event occurs.

Comment: @Yogi , I will add pictures,but for the sake of time, a popup opens when a user clicks on the toolbar icon, imagine a snip icon or image they click in, that triggers the event listener in the popup.js.  That code should only execute when someone  clicks the button, execute meaning code runs at that point.  However, now when I open a webpage it reaches the background script and takes a screenshot.  It shouldn't be doing that if I'm tying that action to a button.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto can you explain at little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simplified Messaging**

As others have already pointed out, the main problem is with your content script. The captureVisibleTab method is called immediately on page load and not when a button is clicked. You can fix this and also simplify your code as shown.

*The code below has been tested and works*

**background.js**

You can remove the popup completely and instead use the onClicked event. This way users only need to click on the extension icon to capture the current tab. This can be done by clearing the default popup handler and adding your own handler as shown:

```
// Allows onClicked to fire when popup was set in manifest
chrome.action.setPopup({ popup: "" });

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.tabs
    .captureVisibleTab(tab.windowId, { format: "png" })
    .then((dataUrl) => {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
        action: "captureVisibleTab",
        tabId: tab.id,
        length: dataUrl.length,
        dataUrl: dataUrl,
      });
    });
});
```

**content.js**

And to the content script add a listener to process the captured image:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
  if (message.action === "captureVisibleTab") {
    // do something...
    // cropScreenshot(message.dataUrl);
  }
});
```

**manifest.json**

If the background script tries to send a message before the content script has loaded it will fail. There is no handler to receive the message. To avoid this problem you can modify [run_at](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/extensionTypes/#type-RunAt) in the manifest to load the content script early. This way your capture button will still work even while the page is still loading ads, etc.

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
      ... etc
```

**Image Cropping**

There are a number of good image cropping libraries available, like [ImageCropper](https://github.com/peterver/vanilla-image-cropper), [Croppr](https://github.com/jamesssooi/Croppr.js), and [Cropper](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs). Each has different features and complexity. You may want to consider one of these in place of your custom code.

Comment: Thank you @Yogi, being done in an extension, I'm not familiar with webpacking and it would be needed for this if I used a library.  I know it's doable, but I went this route to avoid too much add frustration.  Web apps have a lot more freedom than chrome extensions do, learning that the hard way.  Anyway, I'm calling this the answer with the added bit for the background's onClick.  really appreciate your time and response!!

Answer (score 2):

From the codes you send the screenshot is functioning whenever you open a page without listening on user action (button click) might caused by your code structure.

This is the part where it is listening `onMessage` and proceed if action is `captureVisibleTab`.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === "captureVisibleTab") {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, { format: "png" }, function(imageUrl) {
      sendResponse({ imageUrl: imageUrl });
    });
    return true; // Required to indicate that the response will be sent asynchronously
  }
});
```

This part of the code is fine where it only fires `sendMessage` when button is clicked.

```
snip.addEventListener("click", function() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "captureVisibleTab" }, function(response) {
    console.log(response.imageUrl);
  });
});
```

However, in your `content.js` you have this code at the end of the script.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "captureVisibleTab" }, function(response){
    if (response && response.imageUrl) {
      // Call the cropScreenshot function and pass the imageUrl as a parameter
      var imageUrl = response.imageUrl
      cropScreenshot(imageUrl);
    } else {
      console.log("Error capturing visible tab");
    }
});
```

This part of code is not enclosed within any function. This part of code will `sendMessage` with `captureVisibleTab` action. Which means, this part of code will run whenever `content.js` is loaded.

From your `manifest.json`, your content_scripts will runs `content.js` at `document_end`. Which means the last part of the code of content.js is firing whenever the page is loaded.

```
"content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
      "all_frames": false,
      "run_at": "document_end"
```

This might be the reason why your extension is taking screenshot whenever page is loaded. To fix it, you may enclose the last part of code in a function or make some changes to the code structures.

Comment: I've up voted your answer as it is correct.  My answer is similar and I decided to post it anyway as it provides additional details.  +1

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the manifest issue, I was building off an example online and didn't think about that at all